# Should I add $HOME/.local/share to XDG_DATA_DIRS?

Tags: xdg, fish

Currently `XDG_DATA_DIRS` contains `/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop`.

I would like to add `~/.local/share` to the list. My reason is the following:

Now the fish shell can look for vendor completions, functions and config under `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/fish/vendor_completions.d/`, `fish/vendor_functions.d/` and `fish/vendor_conf.d` respectively.
This way a user installed tool that comes with a vendor fish config (installed into `~/.local`) will be able to work out of the box.

I understand `~/.local/share` is not on `XDG_DATA_DIRS` because it is usually `XDG_DATA_HOME`.

My main question:

- Would there be side effects if I updated it to contain (eg in `~/.bashrc` or fish config)?
- Additionally, why is there a separate `XDG_DATA_HOME`?